# Injecting Retrofit using dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

Hi I am learning dagger2 around the web. I found one example where developer tried to execute webservice using retrofit in some way. I have couple of queries.

> 1st Question

What this statement will do `@Inject Retrofit retrofit;` in `MainActivity.java` ?

> 2nd Question

On what sequence or basis below methods of `NetModule.java` execute ?

> 3rd Question

What is the use of AppModule here ?

> 4th Question

What this statement will do  `((AppApplication) getApplication()).getNetComponent().inject(this);` in `MainActivity.java`

Thanks in advance

### NetModule.java

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;
import okhttp3.Cache;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

@Module
public class NetModule {

    String mBaseUrl;

    public NetModule(String mBaseUrl) {
        this.mBaseUrl = mBaseUrl;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Cache provideHttpCache(Application application) {
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
        Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
        return cache;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient(Cache cache) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.cache(cache);
        return client.build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }

}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;

    private String TAG = getClass().getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((AppApplication) getApplication()).getNetComponent().inject(this);


        Call<List<Post>> posts = retrofit.create(Restapi.class).getPosts();

        //Enque the call
        posts.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.body().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### AppModule.java

```
@Module
public class AppModule extends Application {

    Application mApplication;

    public AppModule(Application mApplication) {
        this.mApplication = mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }
}
```

### AppApplication.java

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.nagarro.daggerdemo.dagger.component.DaggerNetComponent;
import com.nagarro.daggerdemo.dagger.component.NetComponent;
import com.nagarro.daggerdemo.dagger.model.AppModule;
import com.nagarro.daggerdemo.dagger.model.NetModule;

public class AppApplication extends Application {

    private NetComponent mNetComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .netModule(new NetModule("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"))
                .build();
    }

    public NetComponent getNetComponent() {
        return mNetComponent;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the name `NetComponent` is a terrible choice, it's actually `SingletonComponent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)It means the variable will be injected.  When you call inject on the Activity, the inject function will use reflection to find all the variables marked with @Inject and fill them in.  (It's actually preferred to use an injected constructor, but that isn't possible for activities or most views).

2)THey execute as needed.  When an instance of a class is injected, Dagger finds the variables it needs to fill in.  Then it walks the methods in the module, looking for one that is annotated with @Provides and returns the correct type.  It will then call it and set the injected variable to the return value.  (This is a slight simplification that doesn't take scope and named injection into account).

3)AppModule would be used to provide the Application, so you don't need to make it a singleton.  This can be useful if you want to use Contexts in places and don't want to have to pass it in down a chain of callers.

4)Its injecting the main activity, as described above.

I really suggest you read some tutorials on Dagger and dependency injection.  You obviously missed some key concepts that you need to understand to use it.